# Is there a purely SwiftUI way to call registerForRemoteNotifications()?

Tags: ios, swiftui

my app has a struct that implements `App`, and this struct uses a custom `AppDelegate`. This is my entire `AppDelegate`:

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return true
  }
}
```

I would like to get rid of this AppDelegate and call `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()` in the `App` implementation. Is this currently possible with SwiftUI 2.0 or later?

Comment: Don't you need device token in `application(_:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:) `?